# “Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance” When Adding to Array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native, dynamic, components

In my application, I am adding components dynamically, which is working. I have now tried to implement additional arrays that store the fields for these components. However, when I try to add to them, I get the error:

```
TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance
```

I added the following line of code, above the array in which indexes are added to an array for each component.

```
this.setState({ disabled: true, arr1: [ ...this.state.arr1, "Test" ] });
```

I declare the array as follows:

```
arr1: []
```

Comment: Need a bit more context. What is the initial `state` object?

Comment: @Nick not sure if the edit I just added is what you mean, but I have made a change.

Comment: Thanks! Can you show the code where you actually create the initial `this.state` value?

Answer (score 0):

It appears like the initial value of `this.state.arr1` is undefined because it may not be defined when initializing state.

If you wish to dynamically add the `arr1` key in your state, you could try something like:

```
const oldArr1 = this.state.arr1 || [];
this.setState({disabled: true, arr1: [...oldArr1, "Test"]});
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You likely have an uninitialized state for `arr1`, which means you're trying to spread a likely undefined value.

If you set your state elsewhere (I suppose you do), you can't be sure that it's initialized properly (see [lifecycles on docs](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)).

Inside your component, initialize the state using a class property or in the constructor:

```
class Thing extends Component {
    //Class property
    state = {
      arr1: []
    }
    //Or in constructor
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);

       this.state = {
         arr1: []
       }
    }

    ...
```

Comment: So I declare 'arr1' inside of 'this.state':

Comment: @LondonMassive As in this example, yes. Choose one of the method though, class property or inside the constructor.